# How to insert multiple strings into specific column with space between?

Tags: php, sql-server

How to insert multiple strings into specific column with space?

Example:

```
$this->database[ABB]->doQuery('INSERT INTO MARKET (Account, User, Rank, ChangeTime) VALUES (?,?,?, GetDate())', $_SESSION['Account'], $user, $rank);
```

The values are sanitized in my full code above this query however I want to combine `Account & User` columns into one (`AccUserInfo`) and when they are inserted, it should insert them like that with space between: `AccEx UserEx`

Is it possible to do that in my php script when its inserted to the MSSQL Server 2005 table?

**I will change the db structure, just wanna know how to include both strings into the query with space between them?**

Comment: you cant change the db structure wwith an insert querry

Comment: I will change the db structure, just wanna know how to include both  strings into the query with space between them?

Comment: im still confused perhaps: `$AccUserInfo=$_SESSION['Account'].' '.$user;`

Comment: I will test it out, but is this vulnerable with the space or it shouldnt add any side effects?

Comment: tested it, and it worked. I mean vulnerable to any malicious behaviour such as injection even when other inputs are already sanitized/removed any html characters as well. Just asking if this space adds any side effect in terms of that?

Comment: its a space - i dont understand how you think a space can be malicious

Comment: Sorry about that but wanted to know as my script is currently, will  this change (the space the way you suggested) to be in anyway malicious for the query?

Comment: no, its fine. (padding for min message limit)

Comment: thanks, post it as answer so i can accept it please. also, yeah its not being counted in the message limit lenght

Comment: honestly still have no idea whats going on, but answered below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to join any 2 stings together with a space:

```
$foo=$cat.' '.$dog;
```

your particular case:

```
$AccUserInfo=$_SESSION['Account'].' '.$user;
```

Comment: Thanks, also I have last question. If I change the space with `:>` as separator or `>>` will this have any vulnerability as I asked a few minutes ago in terms of the space? Column will be inserted like: `AccID:>UserID`

Comment: no letter number or other character that you hard code will create a vulnerability

Comment: The values will be user input but before that they are sanitized, after that I wanna insert them with separator space or `:>` into the table/column. So, this shouldn't cause any problems since they are already sanitized previously and after that in the `$AccUserInfo` they are combined with already stated separator, right? thats what you mean?

Comment: correct, you will be fine as long as the user inputs are sanitized; what ever you add will be safe

Comment: thanks a lot, accepted plus up voted. appreciated a lot